# Docker rootless mode without userns-remap

Tags: linux, docker, rootless

I'm running my docker containers in [rootless mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) in Debian as a systemd user unit without root privileges (e.g. as user `1111`). Additionally, rootless mode uses userns-remap to run my containers with subuids/subgids, so a container started by `1111` will actually run as `363143`.

This causes more trouble than it's worth, the main goal for me is achieved by running the docker daemon as a non-root. How can I disable userns-remap and just run all containers  as `1111`?

Or alternatively if disabling userns-remap isn't possible, can I configure it to not use subuids starting from `363143` but always use `1111` instead?